# Core Data Persistence, Unresolved error

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, persistence

Using a book tutorial, the 3 other Persistence methods worked flawlessly. Getting this message when running simulator:

> 2012-06-01 23:50:52.555 Core Data Persistence[9022:fb03] Unresolved
>   error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x6b92af0
>   {metadata={type = immutable dict,
>   count = 7, entries => 2 : {contents =
>   "NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers"} = {type = immutable, count = 1, values = (  0 : {contents = ""} )}  4 : {contents = "NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion"} = {value = +386, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}  6 :
>   {contents =
>   "NSStoreModelVersionHashes"} = {type = immutable dict, count = 1, entries =>     1 :
>   {contents = "Line"} = {length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes =
>   0x03913bef8e6d277b9119a99fbc7b4adc ... 39db5d5f94ed5507} }    7 :
>   {contents = "NSStoreUUID"} = {contents =
>   "FE367DDA-4009-4CD1-9B8A-D62943668E8E"}   8 : {contents = "NSStoreType"} = {contents = "SQLite"}     9 : {contents = "_NSAutoVacuumLevel"} = {contents = "2"}  10 : {contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion"} =
>   {value = +3, type =
>   kCFNumberSInt32Type} } , reason=The model used to open the store is
>   incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 386;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Line = <03913bef 8e6d277b 9119a99f bc7b4adc 4fec730a 73b61247 39db5d5f 94ed5507>;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>               ""
>           );
>           NSStoreType = SQLite;
>           NSStoreUUID = "FE367DDA-4009-4CD1-9B8A-D62943668E8E";
>           "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>       };
>       reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"; }

Both my entities are set up correctly, here's my file:

```
#import "BIDViewController.h"
#import "BIDAppDelegate.h"

@interface BIDViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDViewController
@synthesize line1;
@synthesize line2;
@synthesize line3;
@synthesize line4;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    BIDAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"Line"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (objects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"There was an error!");
        // Do whatever error handling is appropriate
    }

    for (NSManagedObject *oneObject in objects) {
        NSNumber *lineNum = [oneObject valueForKey:@"lineNum"];
        NSString *lineText = [oneObject valueForKey:@"lineText"];

        NSString *fieldName = [NSString
                               stringWithFormat:@"line%d", [lineNum integerValue]];
        UITextField *theField = [self valueForKey:fieldName];
        theField.text = lineText;
    }

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:app];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.line1 = nil;
    self.line2 = nil;
    self.line3 = nil;
    self.line4 = nil;


}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *) notification {
    BIDAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;
    for (int i = 1; i <=4; i++) {
        NSString *fieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"line%d", i];
        UITextField *theField = [self valueForKey:fieldName];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                                  entityForName:@"Line"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [request setEntity:entityDescription];
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate
                             predicateWithFormat:@"(lineNum = %d)", i];
        [request setPredicate:pred];

        NSManagedObject *theLine = nil;

        NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                                  error:&error];

        if (objects == nil) {
            NSLog(@"There was an error!");
            // Do whatever error handling is appropriate
        }

        if ([objects count] > 0)
            theLine = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
        else 
            theLine = [NSEntityDescription
                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Line"
                       inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [theLine setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"lineNum"];
        [theLine setValue:theField.text forKey:@"lineText"];
    }
    [context save:&error];
}

@end
```

Any thoughts or opinions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you changed your core data model, after initially installing your app in the simulator.

`reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store`

Did you try deleting and reinstalling the app?

Comment: Oh man this Redbull is not kicking in! Yes I had actually changed the type of my entity attribute, fixing one error, which led to this error. Deleting the app and restarting the simulator worked perfect. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Look into the lightweight migration options as well.